How to properly use Databricks Statement Execution API in C# .NET
I need to query Azure Databricks delta lake data using C# .NET
Databricks is now supporting a method known as Statement Execution API.
I have put together a simple console app, which suppose to query Databricks via this API:
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DatabricksApiApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Set up the endpoint and the access token
                string baseUrl = "https://adb-7786225719779619.19.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/sql/statements";
                string accessToken = "{access_token}";
                string warehouseId = "ff7b6377ff77ab94";

                // Prepare the HTTP request
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, baseUrl)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(
                        "{\"statement\":\"SELECT * FROM default.product_1\", \"warehouse_id\":\"{warehouseId}\", \"timeout_seconds\":600}",
                        Encoding.UTF8,
                        "application/json"
                    )
                };
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");

                // Send the request
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                // Check the response
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("Data retrieved successfully!");
                    Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve data. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
                    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Response Body: {responseBody}");
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
                Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}

When I run this code, I receive the following error:
Failed to retrieve data. Status code: BadRequest
Response Body: {"error_code":"INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE","message":"{warehouseId} is not a valid endpoint id."}

As I navigate over to Azure Databricks workspace, select "SQL Warehouses", select the one warehouse I am interested in, select "Connection details" tab - I see the the following entry under the "HTTP Path" field:
/sql/1.0/warehouses/ff7b6377ff77ab94

Naturally, I am making an assumption that "ff7b6377ff77ab94" is the warehouse id, which is required to make use of the Statement Execution API.
Am I doing something wrong or incomplete?

You've got {warehouseId} in your content, but that's not an interpolated string ($"..") so the output is {"statement":"SELECT * FROM default.product_1", "warehouse_id":"{warehouseId}", "timeout_seconds":600}

Thank you! This observation got me through to the next step. If you provide this as an answer - I'm happy to accept

Thanks, but really it’s just a typo, and probably not very useful as an answer..
